# How to rewrite this file_get_contents() snippet using wp_remote_get()

Tags: wp-remote-get

I have this piece of code, which uses file_get_contents(), as far as I know this does not work with WP, can someone help me how to rewrite the following code using wp_remote_get()?

```
$bizt_a = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://karteritesed.hu/biztositok.json"));
$bizt_lista = "";
foreach($bizt_a as $bizt){
$bizt_lista .= "<option value=\"".$bizt."\">".$bizt."</option>";
}
```

Comment: don't forget to indent your code, and remember to escape that output with `esc_attr` and `esc_html`, that JSON might sneak some HTML or script tags!

Answer (score 2):

So take this code:

```php
$bizt_a = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://karteritesed.hu/biztositok.json"));
```

Separate it out so that we do 1 thing per line ( if you pass it straight into `json_decode` what happens if the request fails and that site is down? `json_decode` isn't expecting an error message! It's going to turn around and ask "What's this?!" )

```php
$json = file_get_contents("https://karteritesed.hu/biztositok.json");
$bizt_a = json_decode( $json );
```

Now that each line does 1 thing and only 1 thing, we can ignore the json decoding part, and focus on fetching the contents of that URL.

Lets look up the examples at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_get/

It wants the URL as the first parameter, and the second parameter is where we can give it any additional options. I don't think you need additional options so we can leave that out

```php
$response = wp_remote_get( 'URL goes here...' );
```

`$response` is an array that has the content of the URL, and other things, such as the headers, the response code etc. Afterall don't you want to check it worked? What if it was a 404 not found!!!

So lets do a quick check, remember HTTP 200 means OK  great everything worked:

```php
if ( is_wp_error( $response ) || ( wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response ) != 200 ) ) {
    // something went wrong!!! Abort!!!
}
```

Then we can extract the text:

```php
$responseBody = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
```

And JSON decode it:

```php
$bizt_a = json_decode( $responseBody );
```

Then you can continue like you did before.

Even better, swap `wp_remote_get` for `wp_safe_remote_get` for added protection.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_remote_get/

Note though, that making a request to another server is expensive!! You don't want to do this on every page load or your site will get slow. It also means your site will always be as slow or slower than `karteritesed.hu` because it has to grab that file. Save that JSON somewhere, maybe in a cache etc and things will run faster

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately I had no luck with this solution. After wp_remote_retrive_body I've inserted the following line print_r($responseBody);die(), the strings are there, but don't show up in the form.

Comment: My answer doesn't touch the code that implements the form, and doesn't include a full copy paste solution, so I would need to know exactly what you did. It's also unclear if `json_decode` worked or not, your original code in the question just assumed it would work without checking for error values being returned. Either way if `$responseBody` contains the JSON strings you expected then i have answered your question, you have successfully retrieved the data using `wp_remote_get`